# Remove cookie stored with 'react-cookie', irrespective of domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

I am saving cookies using `react-cookie`, while doing that I set few optins live `maxAge` & `domain`.

Example:

```
cookie.save('xxx', 'data', { path: '/', maxAge: 0000, domain: '.example.com' })
```

Now while removing I have to use same paramenter in options to remove cookies, otherwise due to domain parameter cookies wont get removed!

Example:

```
cookie.remove('name', { path: '/', domain: '.example.com' })
```

But this wont remove a cookie saved with `'beta.example.com'` or `'example.com'`

I want to remove all cookies for my domain irrespective what sub domain is set. I am unable to found a solution for this so far :(

Link to package: [react-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie)

Answer (score -1):

your domain may start with  "http" or "https". please use full address if not removed.